# Set state doesn't work when drop event is fired

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I remove the `setState`(in this case setImgDrag), the state does not take the value of the img selected, basically what I do is get the img from the sidebar and when the `onDragStart` event  is fired  I take the scr of the img and store it in a var called imgDrag, that works perfect, the point is that when I try to set the state of the img that is in the div, the state "imgDrag" does not get set. If you have a better implementation I will accept it.

```
import Img from "./img-card"
 
const  DropImg=()=>{
  const [img,setImg]=useState([])
  const[imgDrag,setImgDrag]=useState()
  const[position,setPosition]=useState({x:0,y:0})
  let imgSelected;

  let getImg=(e)=>{
    let img=e.target.files
    for(let i=0;i<img.length;i++){
      setImg((prevState)=>{return  ( img? [...prevState,URL.createObjectURL(img[i])] : [...prevState]) })
    }
  }

  let dragOver=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    let xPosition=e.clientX
    let yPosition=e.clientY
    setPosition(()=>{return {["x"]:xPosition,["y"]:yPosition}})
    console.log(position)
  }
let drop=(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  setImgDrag(imgSelected)
  console.log(imgDrag)
}
  return (
  <div className="flex bg-gray-400">
    <div className=" bg-gray-800 w-1/4 rem-width-25 px-5 pt-6 h-screen">
      <div className="block">
        <div className="relative bg-teal-500 border rounded  py-12 m-auto text-center  w-11/12   text-white ">
          <input type="file"  id="img" className="absolute top-0  m-auto left-0 cursor-pointer bg-gray-200 border border-gray-300 mb-3 outline-none py-10 px-5 rounded shadow-sm opacity-0" multiple onChange={getImg} />
          Click Here  Or Drop An Image 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid w-full  grid-cols-3 gap-2 mt-10">
        {(img? img.map((src,index)=>{return <Img key={index} id={index} draggable="true" onDragStart={e=>{ imgSelected= e.target.src}} src={src}/>}):null)}
      </div>
    </div>
        <div onDrop={drop} onDragOver={dragOver}  className="w-9/12 h-screen">
        {imgDrag? <Img  src={imgDrag} style={{width:400}}/>: null} 
        {img? null:<p id="drop-here" className="text-center">Drop Image Here!</p>}
        </div>
  </div>)
}
export default DropImg
```

Comment: You can't console log after a state update and expect to get the updated value. Check [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: yeap, you're right, but still the same, the state does not get set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have a problem using a variable - `imgSelected`, so try to also use `useState` for it.

```js
// let imgSelected;
const [imgSelected, setImgSelected] = useState();

...

<div className="grid w-full  grid-cols-3 gap-2 mt-10">
  {(img? img.map((src,index)=>{
      return <Img key={index} 
        id={index} 
        draggable="true" 
        // onDragStart={e=>{ imgSelected= e.target.src}}
        onDragStart={e => setImgSelected(e.target.src) } 
        src={src}/>
      }):null)
  }
</div>
```

Comment: i just created a const and then use the data of it to set the img